# Strip out the code using gradle script

Tags: groovy, gradle

I wanted to write gradle task which reads java files and strip out (remove the code).same as pre-processor in java where we can define conditional code using #if and #endif. I have tried to found some plugin in gradle but not much luck with that, as a last option I can parse the file and do the parsing manually.

Any help or link will be highly appreciated.

Note : I am new to gradle and groovy.

Comment: Which plugin did you try?

Comment: Why are you trying to "strip" code? Could this be a case of an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)? Also an example input and output will help clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: @jalopaba : I searched for it, but didn't found any

Comment: @RaGe : It's project's need, For example, Consider that I have java file which has code like CreateObject obj = new CreateObject(); and I want to create new java (copy)file which may or may not have this code according to some conditions(in java we can use pre-processor and achieve this), I am not sure about gradle

Comment: what preprocessor are you using with Java?

Comment: JavaPP.jar is used as library. and preprocessor was #if and #endif

Comment: There seem to be a bunch of Ant pre-processor tasks. You can call Ant tasks directly from Gradle - wonder if that might be a way you can go. See [here](http://boldinventions.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=81:javapreprocessorusingeclipse)

Comment: I don't want to go by that route either with ant task, do we have anything purely with gradle

Comment: Please let me know if you found anything...i am looking for something similar.